# Button hints using antd framework in vscode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, antd

I'm using Button and Input of antd in vscode. But It shows error on Button and I want to know why.

I have tried Input, and it shows no error. Which is showed in the picture.

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './index.css';
import router from 'umi/router';
import {Input, Button} from 'antd';

export default function() {
  const handleClick=()=>{
    router.push('/homepage/');
  }
  return (
    <div className={styles.normal}>
      <div className={styles.welcome} />
      <h1 className={styles.title}>login</h1>
      <ul className={styles.list}>
        <li><label>username:</label><Input className={styles.input} placeholder="username"/></li>
        <li><label>password:</label><Input className={styles.input} placeholder="password"/></li>
        <li>
          <Button type="primary" shape="round" onClick={handleClick}>login</Button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The actual output shows:

```
<--language:lang-none-->
"message": "Type '{ children: string; type: \"primary\"; shape: \"round\"; onClick: () => void; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<Pick<(Readonly<AnchorButtonProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>) | (Readonly<NativeButtonProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>), \"defaultChecked\" | \"defaultValue\" | ... 257 more ... | \"block\"> & Pick<...> & Pick<...>, \"defaultChecked\" | ... 256 more ... | \"shape\">': defaultChecked, defaultValue, suppressContentEditableWarning, suppressHydrationWarning, and 250 more."
```

plus, I want to ask how to use static resource? The sample project just use the css background url way to show pictures.

[image]

Comment: Hello, I have same problem, too. I'm looking for solution yet but I could not find solution. There is a open issue for antdesign. 
https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/15930

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello I have updated @types/react as 16.8.11 in my package.json. This solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! By the way, node expected version "^6.14.0 || ^8.10.0 || >=9.10.0".

Comment: This might work but downgrading react is not the best solution once antd has already fixed in the problem (antd@3.16.3)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed by antd 3 days ago. Just update your antd to version 3.16.3 and you will be fine.

Execute: `npm i antd@3.16.3 --save` or `yarn antd@3.16.3`

If you want more details, you can find in [this issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/15930)