# Type error while using antd Button with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I use `Button` by `antd@3.16.2` like this:

```
<Button
  type="primary"
  loading={true}
  onClick={console.log}
  block
>
  Do something
</Button>
```

And here is the error I see when try to compile it.

```
Error:(231, 26) TS2740: Type '{ children: string; type: "primary"; loading: boolean; onClick: () => void; block: true; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<Pick<(Readonly<NativeButtonProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>) | (Readonly<AnchorButtonProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>), "children" | "style" | ... 257 more ... | "block"> & Pick<...> & Pick<...>, "children" | ... 256 more ... | "shape">': style, title, className, prefixCls, and 251 more.
```

What does it mean and where should I look to fix this types inconsistency?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you remove `onClick` handler it's still yelling at you?

Comment: i am using this antd and cant see this error. but maybe there can be problem with callback parameter? button onClick props will pass parameter  React.MouseEventHandler or something like this. so try to define your callbak with this parameter.  type myCallBacc: (event: React.MouseEventHandler<any>) => void

Comment: I just removed callback function and the error is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update your antd to version 3.16.3 or newer versions and you will be fine.

Execute: `npm i antd@3.16.3 --save` or `yarn antd@3.16.3`

or

Execute `npm i antd@latest --save` for latest.

If you want more details, you can find in [this issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/15930)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55606270/button-hints-using-antd-framework-in-vscode) just  `@types/react@16.8.11` can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can't place the console.log in onClick method.
if you want you can create some function which in that function is a console log

for example :

```
handleClick = (event) => {
  console.log(event)
}
```

and you can call the function this :

```
<Button
  type="primary"
  loading={true}
  onClick={this.handleClick}
  block
>
  Do something
</Button>
```

Comment: The error I mentioned is not about what kind of a callback I use, because I put `console.log` just as an example. In reality there is my function. The problem is more about TypeScript definitions inconsistency.